# Java - Transer 2 attributes from JSP table to Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I created a table with JSP with an image tag used to select 1 of the items. Now I want to forward two variables f.e. name and lastName. 
I know how to forward 1 variable with the servlet Get method like this;

`'servlet.do?name='+name` But how do I obtain this variable in my Servlet and how can I send two or more attributes?

Comment: show us the code what you have?

Comment: There's no code neccessary to answer this question as seen below. Basically that link was the only line of code I had for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass N-number of attribute while submit likewise,

```
'servlet.do?name='+name+'&SecondAttr='+varValue+'&ThirdAttr='+varValue
```

On Other Hand on Servlet you can get all Requested Parameter likewise,

```
Servlet.java

into doGet/doPost Method,
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String SecondAttr= request.getParameter("SecondAttr");
String ThirdAttr= request.getParameter("ThirdAttr");
```

Then After do whatever you want.